# SvelteKit on:click event listener not behaving correctly on mobile

Tags: events, mobile, svelte, sveltekit

I have an on:click event listener attached to a button in Svelte. When clicked, the color of the button should change to red. When clicked again, it should revert back to the original color. This toggle functionality works as expected on desktop, but when testing on mobile, it doesn't revert back to original color unless after clicking on the button, I click elsewhere on the screen.

I have an up and running site [here](https://spencerwueste.vercel.app/skills), so you can try testing it yourself. I tried in on two different browsers, so hopefully it is not a browser issue. Below is the code I used.

```
    let filters = [
        {filter:'Front-end', color:false},
        {filter:'Back-end', color:false},
        {filter:'Database', color:false},
        {filter:'Cloud', color:false},
        {filter:'Data Science', color:false},
        {filter:'Data Analysis', color:false},
        {filter:'Data Engineering', color:false},
        {filter:'Machine Learning', color:false},
        {filter:'Deep Learning', color:false},
    ];

    const toggleFilter = (e) => {
        const innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML || '';
        console.log(innerHTML)
        const index = filters.findIndex((f) => f.filter === innerHTML);
        console.log(index)
        if (index !== -1) {
            filters[index].color = !filters[index].color;
            filters = [...filters]; // Create a new array to trigger reactivity
        }
    }
    let allFiltersFalse;
    let filterNames;
    $: {
        allFiltersFalse = filters.every(filter => !filter.color);
        filterNames = filters.filter(filter => filter.color);
        filterNames = filterNames.map(filter => filter.filter);
    }


</script>


<section class="mt-8 lg:mb-8">
    <h1 class="text-6xl lg:text-8xl w-3/4 m-auto text-center mb-8">Technical Skills</h1>
    <h2 class="m-auto w-3/4 mb-5">Filter by Domain</h2>
    <div class="m-auto flex flex-wrap items-center w-3/4 gap-5">
        {#each filters as filter, i}
            <button on:click={toggleFilter} class="p-2 hover:bg-primary-500 {filter.color ? "bg-primary-500" : "bg-surface-900"}">{filter.filter}</button>
        {/each}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire premise of `Svelte` is to use declarative code;; you should almost never use `imperative code`; (e.g. `e.target.innerHTML`).
You can achieve your objective by having your **filters** as an array of strings, plus an empty array to watch for selected filters; **selectedFilters**.

```js
let filters = ['Front-end', 'Back-end', 'Database', 'Cloud', 'Data Science', 'Data Analysis', 'Data Engineering', 'Machine Learning', 'Deep Learning' ];    
let selectedFilters = [];
```

Also make a function that takes in your selected filter (from the `on:click`) as a parameter and either appends, or remove it from the **selectedFilters** array depending on whether its already there or not.

```js
function selectFilter(filter) {
        //If selected Filter is in selectedFilters array, remove it
        if (selectedFilters.includes(filter)) {
            selectedFilters = selectedFilters.filter((f) => {
                return f != filter;
            });
        } else {
            //If selected Filter is not in selectedFilters array, add it
            selectedFilters = [...selectedFilters, filter];
        }
    }
```

Render your HTML;

```
<section class="mt-8 lg:mb-8">
    <h1 class="text-6xl lg:text-8xl w-3/4 m-auto text-center mb-8">Technical Skills</h1>
    <h2 class="m-auto w-3/4 mb-5">Filter by Domain</h2>
    <div class="m-auto flex flex-wrap items-center w-3/4 gap-5">
        {#each filters as filter, i}
            <button
                on:click={() => {
                    selectFilter(filter);
                }}
                class="p-2 hover:bg-gray-200 {selectedFilters.includes(filter) ? 'bg-red-300 ' : ''}"
                >{filter}
            </button>
        {/each}
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Wow thank you! So this answer doesn't really solve the problem I had, but I love how you refactored my code. Makes it more elegant. The main problem was with the tailwind "hover" styling is being applied on mobile, which makes no sense since you can't hover on mobile. The solution was to either remove the "hover" styling or add future: {
    hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true,
  } to your tailwind config. Currently it's not part of tailwind, but will be in the future.

Comment: @pandacoderz, you're welcome, apologies also - didn't really get the question. `on:hover` behaves like `on:focus` on touch screens which achieves your goal.